# How to change the homepage of the Android Browser app via code?

Tags: android, browser, sharedpreferences

I looked everywhere, including this post:
[How to change the default Android browser's homepage within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524494/how-to-change-the-default-android-browsers-homepage-within-an-app)

and still I have not found a way to change the homepage of the Browser app.

I am sure though that it can be done, since I saw apps that do it.

After looking at the android source code for the BrowserSettings class, I tried overriding the Browser app's settings with:

```
try {
    Context browserContext = createPackageContext("com.android.browser", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences sp = browserContext.getSharedPreferences("com.android.browser_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

    Editor edidor = sp.edit();
    edidor.putString("homepage", "http://www.newhomepage.com");
    edidor.commit();

} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I received a warning when calling getSharedPreferences():

> Attempt to read preferences file /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml without permission

and this error when calling commit():

> Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.android.browser/shared_prefs/com.android.browser_preferences.xml.bak

I do however request permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" /> <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Can anyone think of a way to make this work? or of a different approach?

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: I answered this here. It isn't possible.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524494/how-to-change-the-default-android-browsers-homepage-within-an-app/